# Colours dots move around when using firefox

Tags: firefox, screen, flicker

Green, blue and black dots show on the screen when I use firefox. They move around and quicker when I write or do a search. Sometimes they appear thicker somtimes less. They don't appear in other programs. I havn't found any descripton of this problem nor any remedy.

One example of how it looks. It changes more often when I write someting then when I just watch it:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its an issue with FF which I have reported to them [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1690223)

The way to fix this in the interim is as follows:

In the browser address bar enter `about:config`

accept the warning message and select `Show All`

[image]

[image]

Then in the address search bar enter `gfx.webrender.all`

[image]

toggle to `false` using the left/right icon at the extreme right.

Follow the same route but this time disable WebRender by setting the `gfx.webrender.force-disabled` flag to `true`by the same method,

[image]

and then restart Firefox.

A further reference about webrender is located [here](https://www.ghacks.net/2020/12/14/how-to-find-out-if-webrender-is-enabled-in-firefox-and-how-to-enable-it-if-it-is-not/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did as you show and restarted the computor but sadly it's still the same. Any other tips and tricks?

Comment: Was it set to True or False when you went to that option? Follow the same route but disable WebRender by setting the prefgfx.webrender.force-disabled` to `true`, and
restart Firefox. What version of FF are you using? apt or snap?

Comment: Wow! It worked! I'm so relieved. It was set to false when I first entered. There was no prefgfx.webrender.force-disabled` but gfx.webrender.force-disabled` and that I changed to true and restarted firefox. And it worked! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Great stuff. Please mark my answer as accepted and up vote it as per [how to accept](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks for the feedback. Sorry about the addition of `pref` to gfx - my bad eyesight!.