# Firefox does not work on the Wayland Windowing System

Tags: firefox, raspberrypi, 20.10, wayland

When I try and launch Firefox on Wayland it looks like this.

[image]

Comment: No, Firefox on Ubuntu w/Wayland runs just fine. It's something else that's screwing up, but Firefox runs on Wayland. I even just verified it on a stock Ubuntu.

Comment: Why is it showing the weird image?

Comment: I have no idea. That'd be the question you *should* have asked rather than asking the question you did ask.

Comment: Could it be the same type of issue answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1321366/307670) which was fixed by changing settings in FF `gfx.webrender`

Comment: I changed the settings and switched back to Wayland but it still showed the same image as above