# My screen have a problem on Chrome and Chromium

Tags: nvidia, graphics, google-chrome, intel-graphics, chromium

I deleted Windows 10 and downloaded Ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. When I use Google Chrome or Chromium, after about 10 minutes my screen starts little pixel bugs. Then it get bigger like the video I added below. I can move mouse but after a few minutes all screen get frozen.

A few weeks ago, I was in a meeting in Zoom and I shared my screen. When I click the share screen button, after about a minute I saw same pixels and my screen froozed. Then other speaker said my screen and camera froozen too; I needed to close laptop because I couldn't do anything.

My laptop is 64 bit Toshiba; Intel® Core™ i3-3110M CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4, GeForce 710M/PCIe/SSE2, graphics driver is intel and my pc has 4 gb ram.

I really like Ubuntu but these problems makes big problem for me; I'd be so happy if you can help me. I couldn't add the photo and video so I posted a link to Youtube:

[Link to Youtube Video.](https://youtu.be/XsES5MdBUFM)

Comment: Can't you just post the video to youtube and then post a link to the youtube video?

Comment: Also, have you tried `sudo apt update; sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` to install the latest Nvidia drivers?

Comment: This seems remarkably similar to [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321361/colours-dots-move-around-when-using-firefox/1321366#1321366) but relates to Firefox. Does the same occur if you use FF not Chrome/Chromium? I think it relates to HDMI and after the "fix", my screen works fine.

Comment: @mchid https://youtu.be/XsES5MdBUFM also I will try the code you wrote me tomorrow

Comment: @24601 yes, it happend at FF too right after when I opened this topic here, how can I fix it? I don't think it is about computer parts, it never happened at Windows 10

Comment: The way to fix it in FF is set out in the linked Q&A. I don't know if it will work - how it will work with Chrome/Chromium though.

Comment: After you install the drivers, you will have to reboot to apply the changes.

Comment: I reboot but it didn't fixed. I also tried Mozilla method but it didn't help either